# Job Scheduling with Yesod

Tags: postgresql, haskell, amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks, yesod

Following problem:

I have a Yesod web app that is connected to a Postgres database (everything is hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk).

My customer wants to define a schedule (day, hour, ...) for things to happen automatically (e.g. sending out a message). E.g.: "every wednesday message A will be sent at 02:00 PM, but does not get sent after 03:00 PM if the server was down in that period". The definition could be saved to a text file on S3 for example.

One lib I found was https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cron which could be used as a basis for my needs with a caveat: if the server is shut down in that particular minute in which a job would be triggered, the message would not be sent when the server is back.

I used DelayedJob (Ruby) in the past and there the scheduled jobs were stored in a database to circumvent this issue. But in Haskell I could only find solutions without database persistence.

Is there anything to look into for Haskell or do I have to build that on my own e.g. use something like http://jdabbs.com/resquing-yesod/ as a starting point)?

Comment: You are already using Yesod, which comes with a companion library called [persistent](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent) which implements, you guessed it, persistent storage. There is a [postgres backend](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-postgresql) for persistent as well.

Comment: Well...I know that and I used ```persistent``` for other projects. I want a scheduler that persists it tasks in a database to recover from a crash/restart, whatever and not an ORM...